# Finding the number of the real roots of $a^x=g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is the inverse function of $f(x)=a^x$

Tags: inverse

**Question** : Let $a$ be a constant which satisfies $0\lt a\lt 1$. Letting $g(x)$ be the inverse function of $f(x)=a^x$, then find the number $N$ of the real roots of $f(x)=g(x)$.

**Motivation** : This is the question which I created. First, I was thinking about the $a\not=1, a\gt0$ case. Then, I found that the $a\gt 1$ case was easy to solve.

The answer for the $a\gt 1$ case: $N=2$ when $1\lt a\lt e^{\frac 1e}$. $N=1$ when $a=e^{\frac 1e}.$ $N=0$ when $a\gt e^{\frac 1e}$.

Then, I found that the $0\lt a\lt 1$ case was not very easy to solove. Tedious calculations led me to an answer, but I'm not sure if it is correct. (I guess that we need divide $0\lt a\lt 1$ into two parts.) Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried using $a^x=e^{alnx}$ ?

Comment: $g(x)=\ln(x)/\ln(a)$, $f(x)=e^{a\ln(x)}$.  Letting $z=\ln(x)$, we have to solve $\dfrac{z}{\ln(a)}=e^{az}$. Now the left hand side is a straight line which is decreasing for $0<a<1$ whereas the right hand side is strictly increasing.

Comment: @BFD: Wait! I think you are wrong. $a^x$is not $e^{a\ln x}$. $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$ is true.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I think you also think $a^x$ as $e^{a\ln x}$. $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$ is true.

Comment: @mathlove shame on me ... Of course you're right.

Comment: Is seems one has to consider $0<a<1/e$ and $1/e<a<1$.  May it be that there are up to three intersections?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I'm interested in why you got $\frac 1e$.

Comment: @mathlove The interesting value is $a'=e^{-e}$ -- I had to much logarithms in my trials.  For $a<a'$ there seem to be three intersections, for $a\geq a'$ there is only one.  How I got this? I've plotted $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(a)e^{x\ln(a)}$ for different values of $a$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: Oh, yes. It is exactly what I guessed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11095/discussion-between-michael-hoppe-and-mathlove)